# String from input and string in runtime aren't equal?

Tags: javascript, string

So I'm trying to read a `<textarea>` input, dividing it into separate words, and then check on each word if it equals to a word in a list of keywords.

I've finished the code, and when I tested, it didn't worked. When I debugged it, I saw that when it compares a string from the `<textarea>` and a constant string, which looks the same, it considers them as unequal.

I've tried to take the string from the `<textarea>` (exactly the same, copy pasted it) and compared it with the constant string statically, and then it became true.

If you know what the problem might be, I'll be glad to hear.
Thanks.

The code:

```
function run() {
    debugger;

    code = document.getElementById("codeArea").value;
    cleanDots();
    words = code.split(" ");
    compile();
}

function compile() {    
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var w = words[i];
        if (w == "test") 
            alert("test - true");
    }
}

function cleanDots() {
    for (var j = 0; j < code.length; j++) {
        if (code.charAt(j) == ".") {
            var p1 = code.substring(0, j);
            var p2 = code.substring(j + 1, code.length);

            code = p1 + " " + p2;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>דוס סקריפט סביבת פיתוח</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;      
        }
        textarea{
            width: 95%;
            padding: 10px;
            height: 700px;
            text-align: right;
            float: right;       
        }
        button{
            width: 95%;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            float: right;
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="codeArea">

    </textarea>
    <button id="submit" onclick="run()">הרץ</button>

    <script src="compiler.js"></script>
    <script src="methods.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try trimming the textarea string

Comment: what is actually not working in the provided code? Don't you get `alert` - call?

Comment: Just tried this and it works fine for me, can you show some more code, like your html?

Comment: Would like to see code in detail, can you plz repost?

Also i suspect something wrong with split here, words = code.split(" ");.
Try words = code.split("");

Comment: I've added the html.
What Suhan suggested will split it to chars, while I need the words.

Comment: this works for me too. in ffox and chromium.

Comment: Try to make both string in lower case before comparing, also just for debugging you can make alert() the length of both strings, hope this could give some idea.

Answer (score 1):

First of all what you are actually doing in the `cleanDots` function is implementing the JavaScript `replace()` method, this function should be like this:

```
function cleanDots() {
    code = code.replace(".", " ");
}
```

```js
function run() {
  debugger;

  code = document.getElementById("codeArea").value;
  cleanDots();
  words = code.split(" ");
  compile();
}

function compile() {
  for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var w = words[i];
    if (w == "test")
      alert("test - true");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
textarea {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 700px;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
button {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="codeArea">

</textarea>
<button id="submit" onclick="run()">הרץ</button>

<script src="compiler.js"></script>
<script src="methods.js"></script>
```

Beside this your code will execute finely.

Answer (score 0):

In your cleanDots function, you want to replace all dots by spaces
you can simply do :

```
function cleanDots() {
      code = code..replace(/[\.]/g, " ");
}
```

with /[.]/g regular expression, you are trying to much all occurences of dot and then replacing it by space.

Answer (score 0):

I truly don't know what was the problem.
I've rewritten some of the code, reopened it in the browser, and it worked.
I couldn't find any differences between the posted code and the new one.

The only differences I found were changing from `if` the `switch`, but I checked and now it works with `if` as well. another thing I've changed was to replace my "`cleanDots`" method with `code.replace(".", " ")`, as *chsdk* suggested. I've checked here as well, and it worked fine with my method too.

The new code:

```
function run() {
        debugger;

        code = document.getElementById("codeArea").value;
        code = code.replace(".", " ");
        words = code.split(" ");
        compile();
}

function compile() {    
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var w = words[i];
        switch(w) { 
            case "הדפס":
                dosPrint();
                break;      
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks anyway.